# Trying to print custom user status discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
import discord from discord.ext import commands,tasks

client = commands.Bot(
    command_prefix='&',
    intents=discord.Intents.all(),
    description=None,
    help_command=commands.MinimalHelpCommand() )

@client.event 
async def on_ready():
    print('Ready')
    await check_status.start()

@tasks.loop(seconds=10) 
async def check_status():
    user = discord.User
    for guild in client.guilds:
        for user in guild.members:
            for activity in user.activities:
                if isinstance(activity, discord.CustomActivity):
                    print(activity)
```

Theres only 1 person in my server (me),
My status is "testrfgergerger"

Expected Output:

```
testrfgergerger
```

Output:

```
testrfgergerger
testrfgergerger
```

(every 10secs)

Comment: Easy debugging solution: print things at different levels of the loop so you can see why the activity is being printed twice. Much quicker than waiting for an answer here. My suspicion is multiple guilds, but it would only take you a few seconds to find out.

Comment: Only 1 guild, 1 member.

Comment: you have 3 nested `for` loops. each of them might have a second member you weren't expecting. I suggest printing every list before looping over it to see which one has more than a single member.

Comment: @iUseVbsLmao Only 1 assumed or found via debugging? Because one of your loops is doing more than one iteration. You just need to find out which one. The alternative is that your function is being called more than once somehow, but that seems unlikely given the code you've shown us.